# Заливка из 4 углов на css

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем времени суток.

Пытаюсь реализовать градиентную заливку в фоне в таблице на css. В инете полно примеров по заливке:

1. сверху вниз
2. с право налево
3. наискосок
4. не 2 цвета а несколько

И в этом разнообразии я не могу найти способ заливки из 4 углов. 4 угла - 4 цвета. Может кто подсказать решение данного вопроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй сделать из углов четыре линейных (можно попробовать и радиальные) полупрозрачных градиента к центру и обрезать, если необходимо.